# What is the difference between rcc and rfc in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component, react-class-based-component

I want a use case example of when react class components are needed for a project over a react functional component and vise versa. I cant seem to understand the difference between the two.

Comment: Class components are discouraged now after hooks has been added

Comment: Some threads: [what is the difference between functional component and class component](/q/35953840), [React functional components vs classical components](/q/38926574), [When to use ES6 class based React components vs. functional ES6 React components?](/q/36097965)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s mostly historical. React components were originally all class components. Function components were introduced in a later version of React. Going forward you should use function components.